# write a text file in Python, line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a text file, line by line. This code is printing a text line by line, but only the last line is stored in the result.txt file.

```
import re
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt"):
    new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
    print new_str
open('result.txt', 'w').write(new_str)
```

Comment: Looks like you want to open the file first (before the loop) and then write data to it on each iteration through the loop (f=open(...) ... then later f.write(new_str))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I don't know why you need the fileinput module, `open` can handle this case as well.
2. Your for-loop goes through all lines and *overrides* `new_str` with the new line. The last line has no next line, so it won't be overridden, so it's the only line that will get saved.

   ```
   import re
   test_f = open('test.txt')
   result_f = open('result.txt', 'a')
   for line in test_f:
       new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
       result_f.write(new_str)

   # also, this too, please:
   test_f.close()
   result_f.close()
   ```
3. You should use the `with` statement to automatically close your files even when your code crashes.

   ```
   import re
   with open('test.txt') as test_f, open('result.txt', 'w') as result_f:
       for line in test_f:
           new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
           result_f.write(new_str)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have `print new_str` for every line in test.txt. But you only write one line to the file **after** the loop. Changing the code to write after each print:

```
outf = open('result.txt', 'w')
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt"):
    new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
    print new_str
    outf.write(new_str + '\n')
outf.close()
```

will do what you want.

Comment: The other thing to note is the `re.sub` is replacing `\n` with `' '`... so even with the `outf.write` in the correct place it's going to look like one big line...

Comment: @JonClements agreed, cheezy fix added.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to add new lines at the end of the file (i.e append)

```
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt"):
new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
with open("f.txt", "a") as f:
f.write(new_str)
```

You can use the f.write line and repeat it until you write everything